# How to formalize this paradox?

Tags: logic, paradoxes

A friend gave me this problem (in the "blue box")

> *An interesting fact about the number $2$.*
>
> *How many times the number $2$ appears in this text?*
>
> *It appears $2$ times.*

Well I see the number two $3$ times but if i put $3$ in "*It appears ... times.*" it becomes false ...

> $(1)$How we can rewrite this paradox in the classical logic (cutting
>   useless parts, can this paradox be reduced to a simple form?)?
>
> $(2)$What is its deep meaning and where comes from?

The weird thing I notice, that maybe is the cause, is that the 3rd phrase try to state something about itslef and the system..even if it is inside the system...

**My intepretation**

My attempt to find a similar "paradox" inside *naive* sets theory's concept is :

lets define two sets  $A=\{2\}$ and $B=\{\delta \}$ , $2$ and $\delta$ are finite ordinals

then lets define a set $X=A\cup B$

We have that $|A|=|B|=1$ and we know that $|X|=|A|+ |B|-|A\cap B|$

now we say that $|X|=\delta$ that can be

$\delta=1$ (if $A\cap B=\{2\}$ ) or

$\delta=2$ (if $A\cap B=\varnothing $ )

then $|A\cup B|=\delta=1 \rightarrow A\cap B=\{2\}$

but $A\cap B=\{2\} \rightarrow ((2\in A) \land (2\in B)) $
and we know that in $B$ ther is only one element so $2=\delta$

If this "paradox" is of the same kind of the first (inside the "blue" box) now I can see better that there is something circular. 
Anyways I'm not able to continue and find a simple (and correct) formula in the language of classical logic that shows this problem, so my questions $(1)$ and $(2)$ are still valid for me.

**UPDATE**

As the user Charles noticed my interpretation I can't redefine define the two objects.

In fact I wanted to obtain the paradox with that:

$i)$ $ A:=\{2\}$

$ii)$ $B=\{|X|\}$

$iii)$ $X = A \cup B$

these tree definition aren't ordered, are given at the same moment,  but the definiton is circular because I use $ii)$ in $iii)$ and viceversa.It is maybe this the origin of the paradox?

But what I am really interested in is:

> $1)'$ Can be my friend's text reduced at this? How can I express this with a formal formula? (Like the Russel's paradox for example)

that is the question 1).

Comment: As mathematical realters would say: definition, definition, definition: where *exactly* does "this text" end? That would, I believe, solve any possible paradox.

Comment: "the number $2$" appears only twice.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a paradox. It's just false. It's interesting that if you were to attempt to correct it, and write "it appears 3 times", it would still be false. But it's still not a paradox. There's no contradiction, it's simply that it is impossible to write a text that correctly states how many times it contains the number 2.

Comment: @Jack M: why not make than an answer?

Comment: Fill in the blank with any word to make a correct sentence: "This sentence does not contain the word ______ ".

Comment: I would assert the statement above is false, because I didn't find an interesting fact about the number 2. :)

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't think it does solve "any possible paradox". Quine presents several similar constructions where it indisputably doesn't. For example: «The sentence in guillemot quotes in the comment at the URL http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379230/number-two-and-paradox#comment812190_379230 is false.» is clear, meaningful, well-defined, and unambiguous, but impossible to assign a truth value.

Comment: I see that someone has voted to close this question. To improve the question, you can include additional information on where you encountered the problem, and your thoughts on the matter. Separately, some contributors here have a distaste for "paradox" questions, because the site could be swamped with them, so the close vote could be related to that. It's advisable to make questions about paradoxes as informative and high-quality as possible.

Comment: @MJD, I suspect DonAntonio meant, any possible paradox *in this question about appearances of the number 2*.

Comment: Even if he did mean that, quibbling about "where exactly does 'this text' end" will not resolve every possible paradox of this type.

Comment: @Gerry 
For example, one can follow the same recipe I suggested above, replacing the phrase "this text" with "the text in the gray box at the URL …".  One shouldn't need to do that, since that is most likely what everyone understood by "this text" anyway, but the fact that such an easy solution is available should make clear the poverty of the argument from quibbling over the boundaries of the self-reference.

Comment: @MJD, I meant in *this* thread, not in general. Gerry's right.

Comment: As my comment at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379230/number-two-and-paradox?noredirect=1#comment812218_379230 should make clear, quibbling over the boundaries of the self-reference cannot resolve the issue in *this* thread, at least insofar as there is any issue to resolve.

Comment: @JackM, you say "it is impossible to write a text that correctly states how many times it contains the number 2."  What about "This sentence contains the number 2 2 times."

Comment: @CarlMummert yes, was a bit incoplete, mmh a friend asked me that question 

*An interesting fact about the number 2.

How many times the number 2 appears in this text?

It appears 2 times."*

Comment: @CarlMummert About my thoughts : seems me it has something to do with the liar paradox..but seems me a bit different...the question is: *How we can write this paradox in the classical logic? What is its deep meaning and where comes from?* 
What I think about this is that the truth 3rd phrase of the question depends on the truth of the first two phrases and the 3rd (itself)...What I can think is how can be formalized/generalized this paradox. And what is its real cause.
Thanks

Comment: Improved question @CarlMummert

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't know if is so, that is the reason I asked here, by the way my qestions are two and clear I think.

Comment: @MJD S is impossible to assign a truth value? If yes can you say me the real deep cause of this and the "general schema" of this kind of constructions?  If Quine presents similar contructions, what are his conclusions? That will answer to at least one of my questions. Thanks in advance

Comment: @MJD What do you mean with :"quibbling over the boundaries of the self-reference cannot resolve the issue in this thread, at least insofar as there is any issue to resolve."?

Comment: @MphLee Faced with this kind of question, many mathematicians will try to evade it my claiming that there is something illegitimate, incorrect, or ambiguous about the way the question refers to its own text. Whether or not there is such a problem, it is not an essential problem, and the question can be reformulated in a way that avoids it.

Comment: The third line says: *"It appears 2 times."* What would be wrong with replacing the third line with ***"The number 2 appears 3 times."***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an attempt to answer the new question.

I don't think this is a paradox. You've already defined $X$ and $\delta$ so it's not legitimate to redefine them with

> now we say that $|X|=\delta$ that can be

If this is instead treated as a condition

> For what $\delta$ does $|X|=\delta$?

then the answer is simple: there are no such $\delta.$

Comment: ... if you put it in this way..this is the right solution, but it is obvious to me that my interpretation changed the real nature of the text that my friend gave me..In the first version of the question, I did't added my interpretation for this reason. The purpose of my question ( my two qestions ara the same) is to obtain a "pure logic interpretation" of the paradox. Really I don't know how to rerwrite the questions.

but +1 because it is related with my interpretation (attempt)

Comment: I wanted to obtain the paradox with that
$A:=\{2\}$, $B=\{|X|\}$ and $X = A \cup B$

these tree definition aren't ordered, are given at the same moment,  but the definiton is circular.. is maybe that the origin of the paradox? But what I am really interested in is: can be my friend's text reduced at this? How can I express this with a formal formula? (Like the Russel's paradox for example)

Answer (score 11):

```
An interesting fact about the number 2:
How many times does the number 2 appears in this text?
It appears 2+1 times.
```

Comment: flagged, because it doens't help me, and it has not a description.

Comment: @MphLee: And to think I voted for your question, and to reopen it!

Comment: I can say you thanks, anyways your answer make more confusion in my mind, is indeed interesting... but not helpfull sorry

Comment: @MphLee The digit 2 appears three times in this snippet. Three is equal to two plus one.

Comment: @Akamis Yea I got that...